# Mercurial hg flag syntax for config property not working

Tags: mercurial, clone, config, tortoisehg

I have a repository that needs some [hostfingerprints] key to be working.
They told me to add an --insecure flag so it doesn't ask me for the key, but it didn't work.

hg clone --insecure pathToRepository PathForTheFolderToClone

I tried instead to give the property i should have in a hgrc file, when the repository is cloned:

[hostfingerprints]
hg.website.com = 88:88:88.....

But how do you use this property?. It tells me it has bad syntax:

```
*`hg clone --config hostfingerprints.hg.website.com = 88:88:88:88:88...88:88 pathToRepository PathForTheFolderToClone`*
```

Here is the error:

```
*abort: malformed --config option: 'hostfingerprints.hg.website.com' (use --config section.name=value)*
```

How do i write it, then?
And why the --insecure flag doesn't work in the first place?

Comment: Add the config parameter to `hgrc`, and just run `hg clone <src> <dest>`.  leave off the `--config` option.

Comment: @MarkTolonen But where do i put that file so it reads it? I don't have any repository downloaded. I´m doing a clone.

Comment: In the global configure file. On windows it is Mercurial.ini in the user directory. on Linux, it is .hgrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the hostfingerprint in your global config file, then do a normal clone.  `--insecure` will no longer be needed.

From the [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#files) docs:

> On Unix, the following files are consulted:
>
> - /.hg/hgrc (per-repository)
> - $HOME/.hgrc (per-user)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc (per-installation)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc (per-installation)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc (per-system)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc (per-system)
>
> On Windows, the following files are consulted:
>
> - /.hg/hgrc (per-repository)
> - %USERPROFILE%.hgrc (per-user)
> - %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini (per-user)
> - %HOME%.hgrc (per-user)
> - %HOME%\Mercurial.ini (per-user)
> - \Mercurial.ini (per-installation)
> - \hgrc.d*.rc (per-installation)
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercurial (per-installation)

[hostfingerprints](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hostfingerprints) looks like:

```
[hostfingerprints]
hg.intevation.org = fa:1f:d9:48:f1:e7:74:30:38:8d:d8:58:b6:94:b8:58:28:7d:8b:d0
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Anyway, my SourceTree app ignored that warning and cloned the repo. But this solution would work too. THanks.